# Grizzly + Jersey Get Init or Context parameters from @Context ServletContext

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, grizzly

I am new to Grizzly + Jersey and currently it works well. But I found I can not get the Init or Context parameters from @Context ServletContext. Below is my code.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {

        GrizzlyWebServer ws = new GrizzlyWebServer(9998);
        ServletAdapter jAdapter = new ServletAdapter();
        jAdapter.setContextPath("/api");
        jAdapter.setServletInstance(new ServletContainer());                
        jAdapter.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "test.ui.controller");
        jAdapter.addInitParameter("test1","test1");   
        jAdapter.addContextParameter("test2","test2");   
        ws.addGrizzlyAdapter(jAdapter, null);

        ws.start();
        System.out.println("Running... please press enter to stop the server.");

        System.in.read();
        ws.stop();

    }
```

And I try to get the parameters from @Context like follow.

```
@Path("/home")
public class LoginController {
    @GET 
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getIt(@Context HttpServletRequest req,@Context ServletContext context) {                      
        System.out.println(context.getAttribute("test1"));
            System.out.println(context.getAttribute("test2")); 
            System.out.println(context.getInitParameter("test1"));
            System.out.println(context.getInitParameter("test2"));

        return "hello";
    }       
}
```

But all my tries are failed. The outputs are null, null, null, null.

Comment: this is a known issue in Jersey (http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1047); I presume you are using Grizzly2, right? It should work with Grizzly 1.x. BTW it is already fixed in Jersey 2.0, so you might take a look at it.. see